# Landing page vs blog post - which to choose [ Content marketing ]

Tags: seo, blog, marketing, landing-page

When it comes to content marketing I keep on reading about the great use of landing pages that companies like Zapier or Canva do.

But blog posts is also everywhere and it seems to work well too.

My question is, how do we decide if we should create a blog post for a landing page with the intention of getting potential customers?

It seems to me, a landing page can convert much better as the whole purpose of it is to convert a user and explain the product features.

On the other hand, a blog post can mention the product as a possible solution to the user search or just contain a big banner advertising it if the topic is not fully related. But most blog posts won't be focusing only on the product. Usually trying to provide value to the visitor.

Answer (score 1):

Using both contents can be useful for promoting a product. E.g., the landing page presents a party room in a restaurant. A blog post can sell ideas for visiting this room, e.g., "Party with colleagues for 10 persons (localization)" or "Celebrating the 7th birthday for 3 adults and 12 children next to me". Creating reciprocal links between the landing page and blog article (s) that represent the entities of the targeted content can help.

Comment: Wouldn't both URLs be committing keyword cannibalization to each other then? If both target "party room restaurant" keywords?

Which will Google pick first if someone Google "party room restaurant"? Which one do WE want to rank first?

Comment: In the content of blog posts, you can link to the landing page for all mentions of the subject of the content of the landing page. E.g., for "party room of ZZZ restaurant".

Comment: In general, as always, "Content is king" and much depends on the details.